# Pivoting query giving nulls for other required columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following table:

```
 create table table1 (
      Id int not null auto_increment,
      JobId varchar(255) not null,
      FieldOrder int(11) not null,
      FieldName varchar(255) not null,
      FieldValue varchar(255) not null,
      primary key (Id)
    );
```

It has the following data:

```
| Id  | JobId | FieldOrder | FieldName    | FieldValue |
| --- | ----- | ---------- | ------------ | ---------- |
| 1   | 1     | 1          | Customer Id  | C01        |
| 2   | 1     | 2          | Order Number | 3923       |
| 3   | 1     | 3          | Architect Id | DK         |
| 4   | 2     | 1          | Customer Id  | C02        |
| 5   | 2     | 2          | Order Number | 23         |
| 6   | 2     | 3          | Architect Id | AJ         |
| 7   | 3     | 1          | Customer Id  | C03        |
| 8   | 3     | 2          | Plot Id      | 3          |
| 9   | 3     | 3          | Architect Id |            |
```

I am trying to write a pivoting query so that I can get the following:

```
+-------------+--------------+--------------+
| customer_id | order_number | architect_id |
+-------------+--------------+--------------+
| C01         | 3923         | DK           |
| C02         | 23           | AJ           |
| C03         |              |              |
+-------------+--------------+--------------+
```

**CURRENT PROGRESS**

So far my query looks like this:

```
select case
           when FieldName = 'Customer Id' then FieldValue
       end as "customer_id",
      case
          when FieldName = 'Order Number' then FieldValue
      end as "order_number",
      case
          when FieldName = 'Architect Id' then FieldValue
      end as "architect_id"
from table1
group by JobId;
```

Locally, this gives me the following:

```
+-------------+--------------+--------------+
| customer_id | order_number | architect_id |
+-------------+--------------+--------------+
| C01         | NULL         | NULL         |
| C02         | NULL         | NULL         |
| C03         | NULL         | NULL         |
+-------------+--------------+--------------+
```

I suspect because when I do `group by` I no longer has access to my fields, so I'm stuck, I'm not really sure how I can get it to work.

I have created a [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/wbThNLLD44XRm51egMWuzf/0) too, though it won't even run due to some defaulted setting.

Comment: Your query is invalid. You group by jobid, but select an expression on fieldname and fieldvalue. There are possibly many fieldname and fieldvalue per jobid, so which shall the DBMS use? It seems you are in MySQL's infamous cheat mode. That's a bad idea. `SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';` to ensure you get a syntax error on such invalid queries.

Comment: Isn't it horrible to work with key/value tables? Imagine a job table that simply contains a customer_id, order_number and architect_id. Wouldn't that be wonderful? That would even prevent you from entering customer IDs, order numbers or architects that don't exist.

Comment: You're right it is horrible :( I did not create this table though, I'm just writing a query to get some stuff out. Ideally, we'd be given time to refactor things.

Comment: Maybe then you can create a view based on Gordon's approach. Then you don't have to do that in about every query that works with this table.

Comment: That's a good shout, I'll do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want aggregation:

```
select jobid,
       max(case when FieldName = 'Customer Id' then FieldValue
           end) as customer_id,
       max(case when FieldName = 'Order Number' then FieldValue
           end) as order_number,
       max(case when FieldName = 'Architect Id' then FieldValue
           end) as architect_id
from table1
group by JobId;
```

Notes:

- I added `jobid` to the `select`.  Normally, you would want to distinguish the rows.
- Don't escape identifiers that don't need to be escaped.  I removed the double quotes.  They are not needed.